# DB2 ODBC C++ call procedure and get back the value

Tags: c++, odbc, procedure, out

In my DB2 database I have a procedure with name get_mood. The first parameter is IN Integer, the second is OUT varchar(50).
With that code I try to get back the value:

```
    SQLHANDLE hstmt;
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);
    char *value = new char();
    SQLINTEGER length = 0;
    strcpy(stmt, "call get_mood(2201, ?)";
    SQLRETURN cliRC = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)stmt, SQL_NTS);
    SQLSMALLINT cbParm1 = SQL_NTS;
    cliRC = SQLBindParameter(hstmt,
                       1,
                       SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT,
                       SQL_C_CHAR,
                       SQL_VARCHAR,
                       SQL_MAX_CHAR_LITERAL_LEN,
                       SQL_MAX_CHAR_LITERAL_LEN,
                       &value,
                       length,
                       NULL);
    cliRC = SQLExecute(hstmt);
    if (cliRC == SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND) {
        std::cout << "no data" << std::endl;
    }
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
    std::cout << std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(value)) << std::endl;
```

When I try the call in IBM Data Studio, I get a value. But here it is empty. What I made wrong?

Comment: `char *value = new char();` -- `&value` -- Explain the reason for doing this.  It seems you're confused as to what it means when a function requires a buffer.

Comment: First it was = NULL, but I changed it for testing purposes.

Comment: C++ isn't a language where you could just do things without knowing exactly what you're doing.  First, that `new char()` allocates memory for a single character.  Why do that when you could have just done `char value;`?  But it gets worse than that when you now use `&value` in the SQL call.  You are now sending it the address of a pointer instead of the buffer.  If you had just done `char value;`, then `&value` would make sense.  So you need to sort out exactly what that SQL call requires, and give it the correct arguments.  Maybe that is the reason why things are not working.

Comment: Dear Paul. Your comment means, no one should learn C++. And unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: No, my comment is that you should learn C++, but it is obvious you're missing certain fundamentals of the language.  Why not simply use a char array, i.e. `char value [100];`?  Then in the call, just specify `value`, not `&value`, and tell it that the length you want is 100 or 99,.  Then there is no need to fool around with `new` or anything like that.  It would be a straightforward, understandable piece of code.

Comment: CRazy. But that I also tried. Result: ��P